# Docker build failing to reach debian repo

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

The host server can reach internet but the dockerfile build cant reach internet to pull the repos

**Host server reaching internet**

```
[root@jenkins2 ~]# ping archive.debian.org
PING archive.debian.org (130.89.148.13) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from klecker-archive.debian.org (130.89.148.13): icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=161 ms
64 bytes from klecker-archive.debian.org (130.89.148.13): icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=161 ms
64 bytes from klecker-archive.debian.org (130.89.148.13): icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=162 ms
```

**error**

```
 ---> Running in 04379d56c33b
Err:1 http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.debian.org'
Err:2 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**This is a AWS machine and the Outbound rule is All,all,0.0.0.0/0**

Need guidance  where the issue is and how to proceed

Comment: try to run apt-get update first

Comment: Do you have this error since several days? It says “Temporary failure” so it may work again soon, please try again in a few minutes.

Comment: this is there from 3 days now. I dont know the history of this server but am trying to help fix this.

Comment: also ```[root@jenkins2 ~]# docker run busybox ping google.com
ping: bad address 'google.com'
``` fails

Comment: I have the same problem